# table layout doesn't appear in the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tablelayout

I have created a fragment which should display table of buttons. I used table layout to create a table. But the button table doesn't display in the fragment. What is the problem related to this code and how can I overcome this???

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList buttons = new ArrayList();

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this.getActivity());

    //Set a TableLayout to add buttons
    TableLayout tl= new TableLayout(getActivity());

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    tl.setLayoutParams(params);
    tl.setOrientation(TableLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this.getActivity());
        LayoutParams paramrow = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(paramrow);
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            Button button = new Button(getActivity());
            button.setText("testing");
            button.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            LayoutParams parab = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            button.setLayoutParams(parab);
            row.addView(button);
            buttons.add(button);
        }
        tl.addView(row);
    }  
   sv.addView(tl);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for creating the views programmatically?

Comment: yes. The number of buttons will decided on a table in the database..

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong type of LayoutParams in at least two places. Views need to use the type of LayoutParams that correspond to their container. Therefore Views contained directly in a TableLayout - i.e., the TableRows - should use `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. The Views contained in TableRows - the Buttons, in this case - should use `TableRow.LayoutParams`. And finally, the TableLayout is in a ScrollView, so it should use `ScrollView.LayoutParams`, which is actually `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, since ScrollView extends FrameLayout.

It also appears that you're not adding the ScrollView to the Fragment's View anywhere. I would mention, too, that it might be preferable to define the ScrollView and the TableLayout in layout xml, inflate this layout in `onCreateView()`, and dynamically create only what needs to be - i.e., the TableRows and Buttons.